# every time I try to use one of my features (if/else) it crashes cmd - Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement, cmd, passwords

so I am creating a test password program and my problem is every time I try to use the create a new password feature it crashes the CMD at the moment I am kinda new to Batch programming so sorry if I over/under codded enter code here

here is the main code that is crashing CMD

```
:create
cls
if exist C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Password.txt (
goto password1
) else (
set /p Password=What would you like your new password to be.
echo %Password% > C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Password.txt
echo your new password is %Password%
pause
goto start
)
:password1
set /p Password1= A password has already been created to change it please  type           the last known password
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Password.txt) do (
set Text=%%a)
if %Password1%==%Text% goto correct
echo Incorrect!
pause
goto start
:correct
set /p password2=Correct! What would you like your new password to be.
echo %password2% > C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Password.txt
echo Your new password is %password2%
pause
goto start
```

here is all the code

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
:start
color a
echo Welcome to the password program with this program you can securely store    personal data,
echo your options for this program are
echo.
echo Create - (Create a new password)
echo.
echo Check - (Check if your password is right)
echo.
echo Enter - (Enter to check your personal data)
echo.
set /p Program=What would you like to do.
goto !Program!

:create
cls
if exist C:\Users\!Username!\Documents\Password.txt ( 
goto password1
 ) else(
set /p Password=What would you like your new password to be.
echo !Password! > C:\Users\!Username!\Documents\Password.txt
echo your new password is !Password!
pause
goto start
 )
:password1
set /p Password1= A password has already been created to change it please type     the last known password
for /f "Delims=" %%a in (C:\Users\!Username!\Documents\Password.txt) do (
set Text=%%a)
if !Password1!==!Text! goto correct
echo Incorrect!
pause
goto start

:correct 
set /p password2=Correct! What would you like your new password to be.
echo !password2! > C:\Users\!Username!\Documents\Password.txt
echo Your new password is !password2!
pause
goto start

REM Not using this at the moment
:check
cls

REM Not using this at the moment
:enter
cls
```

sorry if this question has already been answered before I am just new to batch coding

Comment: It "crashes the cmd"? What exactly happens? Do you get error messages?

Comment: Please read this help topic: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having is related to variable expansion in batch scripts.

Since your code, eg.

```
(
set /p Password=What would you like your new password to be.
echo %Password% > C:\Users\%Username%\Documents\Password.txt
echo your new password is %Password%
pause
goto start
)
```

is in a block, %Password% retains the value it had before the block (ie. empty, at the first run).

Use delayed expansion to get around that (see earlier link).

Comment: Sorry but I don't really know where to put setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
SET VAR=Hello
FOR /L %%a in (1,1,2) do (
    echo !VAR!
    SET VAR=Goodbye
)

or what to type in it

once again sorry

Comment: Thats an example code. You put setlocal enabledelayedexpansion at the first line of your program, and then use ! instead of % around your variables.

Comment: so I changed the the %'s to !'s but it still crashes when I type in "create"

P.S. I will change the above code so that you can see what I put

Comment: closes with no "Press any key to continue" or a error message

Comment: Start your script from the command line, don't double click it in explorer to see any messages. Fwiw, it definitely goes to pause on create, when i try it.

Comment: Please copy and paste any error message that appears into your question @Fireflame.